# Does jconsole strip out line endings?

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I'm trying to paste a String into an `MBean` attribute using `jconsole`.
Of course, I've done this 1e3 times with no difficulties.

However, if the string I'm pasting includes line endings, `jconsole` appears to replace these with spaces - and it does so without telling me!

Is this true? And if it is true, **how can I get a String with line endings into `jconsole`?**

**Notes.** I'm using `Mac OS X` and pasting in strings with Unix line endings.
A colleague has tried on Windows with Windows line endings.
We've both tried to paste strings in containing line endings from the other OS, but aren't sure we've managed to paste the right chars.
We're both using `Sun/Oracle's standard JDK 1.7`